# Chocolate flavour without the sediment?

Tags: flavor, chocolate

Is there a chocolate flavour liquid without the sediment and no milk in it?

Comment: Seems pretty likely you meant "sediment", but yeah, clarifying like Stephie asked would be very helpful. (What are you using it for, do hot chocolate mix and chocolate syrup not work for you, etc?)

Comment: I guess my first question would be: have you tried just chocolate and water? For example, dissolving cocoa powder in warm water? I add water gradually, and depending on how much water I add, I get a pretty sediment-free liquid/paste/syrup that I can incorporate into recipes...

Answer (score 2):

LorAnn makes a consumer-grade chocolate flavoring:

http://www.lorannoils.com/1-dram-size/chocolate-flavor-0170-dram

You'd use it in a fashion similar to vanilla extract, though it's more concentrated. It's available at candy supply stores, and online. It has a very strong color, so be careful about adding it to things that you want to be white.

I use creme de cacao (basically, chocolate liqueur) for making frosting. It's quite sweet and is much less concentrated than the chocolate flavoring. (It's also a nice addition to milk, kind of a grown-up chocolate milk.) It's available at any liquor store.